# how to get the latest version of hudi table

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-hudi

I have a spark streaming job in which listens to kinesis stream, then it writes it to hudi table, what I want to do is say for example I added these two records to hudi table:

```
| user_id  | name           | timestamp
| -------- | -------------- |----------
| 1        | name1          |1.1.1
| 2        | name2          |1.1.1
```

this should be reflected in the hudi table initially, but what if I edited in the second record to have the name `name2_new`

what I expect is that I will have three records each with their timestamp like this:

```
| user_id  | name           | timestamp
| -------- | -------------- |----------
| 1        | name1          |1.1.1
| 2        | name2          |1.1.1
| 2        | name2_new      |2.2.2
```

when I query this in athena I get as expected the three records, but what if I want extra analysis in which I want the last version of the records which must be something like this (because I updated in the record 2):

```
| user_id  | name           | timestamp
| -------- | -------------- |----------
| 1        | name1          |1.1.1
| 2        | name2_new      |2.2.2
```

is there any idea how I can get the latest version only?

here's the glue job I used to create the hudi table:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp, monotonically_increasing_id, to_date, when
import datetime
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

import boto3

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ["JOB_NAME", "database_name", "kinesis_table_name", "starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator",
                           "hudi_table_name", "window_size", "s3_path_hudi", "s3_path_spark"])

spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer').config(
    'spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet', 'false').getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

database_name = args["database_name"]
kinesis_table_name = args["kinesis_table_name"]
hudi_table_name = args["hudi_table_name"]
s3_path_hudi = args["s3_path_hudi"]
s3_path_spark = args["s3_path_spark"]

print("***********")
print(f"""
database_name  {database_name}
kinesis_table_name = {kinesis_table_name}
hudi_table_name ={hudi_table_name}
s3_path_hudi = {s3_path_hudi}
s3_path_spark = {s3_path_spark}
""")
# can be set to "latest", "trim_horizon" or "earliest"
starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator = args["starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator"]

# The amount of time to spend processing each batch
window_size = args["window_size"]

data_frame_DataSource0 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database=database_name,
    table_name=kinesis_table_name,
    transformation_ctx="DataSource0",
    additional_options={"inferSchema": "true", "startingPosition": starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator}
)

# config
commonConfig = {
    'path': s3_path_hudi
}


hudiWriteConfig = {
    'className': 'org.apache.hudi',
    'hoodie.table.name': hudi_table_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.table.type': 'MERGE_ON_READ',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'timestamp',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'user_id,timestamp',
    #'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'year:SIMPLE,month:SIMPLE,day:SIMPLE',
    #'hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class': 'org.apache.hudi.keygen.CustomKeyGenerator',
    #'hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.timestamp.type': 'DATE_STRING',
    #'hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.input.dateformat': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    #'hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.output.dateformat': 'yyyy/MM/dd'
}

hudiGlueConfig = {
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.sync_as_datasource': 'false',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database': database_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': hudi_table_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc': 'false',
    #'hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning': 'false',
    #'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor',
    #'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': 'year,month,day'
}


combinedConf = {
    **commonConfig,
    **hudiWriteConfig,
    **hudiGlueConfig
}


# ensure the incomong record has the correct current schema, new fresh columns are fine, if a column exists in current schema but not in incoming record then manually add before inserting
def evolveSchema(kinesis_df, table, forcecast=False):
    try:
        # get existing table's schema
        print("in evolve schema")
        kinesis_df.show(truncate=False)
        
        glue_catalog_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM " + table + " LIMIT 0")
        # sanitize for hudi specific system columns
        #columns_to_drop = ['_hoodie_commit_time', '_hoodie_commit_seqno', '_hoodie_record_key',
        #                   '_hoodie_partition_path', '_hoodie_file_name']
        
        columns_to_drop = ['_hoodie_commit_time', '_hoodie_commit_seqno', '_hoodie_record_key',
                            '_hoodie_file_name']
        glue_catalog_df_sanitized = glue_catalog_df.drop(*columns_to_drop)
        if (kinesis_df.schema != glue_catalog_df_sanitized.schema):
            merged_df = kinesis_df.unionByName(glue_catalog_df_sanitized, allowMissingColumns=True)
        return (merged_df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return (kinesis_df)


def processBatch(data_frame, batchId):
    
    print("data frame is")
    data_frame.show(truncate=False)
    
    schema_main = StructType(
    [
        StructField('data', StringType(), True),
        StructField('metadata', StringType(), True)
    ]
    )

    schema_data = StructType(
    [
    StructField("user_id",IntegerType(),True), 
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("address", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("email", StringType(), True)
    ]
    )

    schema_metadata = StructType(
    [
        StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
        StructField("record-type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("operation", StringType(), True),
        StructField("partition-key-type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("schema-name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("table-name"   , StringType(), True),
        StructField("transaction-id", StringType(), True)
    ]
    )

    data_frame = data_frame.withColumn("$json$data_infer_schema$_temporary$", from_json("$json$data_infer_schema$_temporary$", schema_main)).select(col("$json$data_infer_schema$_temporary$.*")).\
    withColumn("data",from_json("data", schema_data)).\
    withColumn("metadata",from_json("metadata", schema_metadata)).select(col("data.*"),col("metadata.timestamp"))
    
    print("data frame is")
    data_frame.show(truncate=False)
    
    #column_headers = list(data_frame.columns)
    #print("The Column Header :", column_headers)
    #data_frame.printSchema()
    
    if (data_frame.count() > 0):
        kinesis_dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_frame, glueContext, "from_kinesis_data_frame")
        #print("dynamoic frame is")
        #kinesis_dynamic_frame.show(truncate=False)
        #print('d')
        kinesis_data_frame = kinesis_dynamic_frame.toDF()
        print("kinesis is")
        kinesis_data_frame.show(truncate=False)
        
        kinesis_data_frame = evolveSchema(kinesis_data_frame, database_name + '.' + hudi_table_name, False)
       
        glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(kinesis_data_frame, glueContext, "kinesis_data_frame"),
            connection_type="custom.spark",
            connection_options=combinedConf
        )

glueContext.forEachBatch(
    frame=data_frame_DataSource0,
    batch_function=processBatch,
    options={
        "windowSize": window_size,
        "checkpointLocation": s3_path_spark
    }
)

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this kind of application, we upsert the table and we choose the record with the biggest timestamp when the keys match between the new coming records and the existing records. But since you need the history of all the updates, you have two options to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Create a new table containing the last version of each record by duplicating your job sinks (`kinesis -> full_history_table`, `kinesis -> last_state_table`), or create a stream (mini batches) on the first table using incremental queries (`kinesis -> full_history_table -> last_state_table`), in this case you will have the result for your two queries without the need to aggregate the data
2. Aggregate the table on each query: if you query is not frequent, you can aggregate the data on the fly using the window function. You can create a view and apply you query on it:

```
SELECT user_id, name, timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn
    FROM TABLE_NAME t
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```